# Vectorizing in Multiple Dimensions

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have the following for loop in my Matlab code I'd like to get rid of:

```
for i=1:size(thePolygon,3)            
    activeValues(:,i) = sum(normalVectors.*thePolygon(:,:,i),2);
    checkValues(:,i) = sign(activeValues(:,i)-sum(normalVectors.*thePolygon3(:,:,i),2));
end
```

I tried replacing `i` with `1:size(thePolygon,3)`, but the dimensions don't line up for the element-by-element multiplication, and I'm not sure what else to try. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Add 4 spaces in front of lines of code for nice formatting.

Comment: Also, you have `thePolygon` and `thePolygon3`. Are those meant to be different?

Comment: thePolygon3 is a rotation of thePolygon.  `thePolygon3 = circshift(thePolygon,2)`

Comment: Is there any real reason to get rid of the loop?  Vectorizing code can be very error prone, and recent versions of Matlab have good JIT compilation of m-files.  Profile your code before you start vectorizing things.

Comment: @sfstewman See my solution, the vectorized version is actually significantly slower!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to test without example data but:

```
activeValues = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, normalVectors, thePolygon), 2))
```

OK so first some test data:

```
a = rand(3,3,3);
b = rand(3,3);
```

now we test yours

```
for i=1:size(a,3)
    c(:,i) = sum(b.*a(:,:,i),2);
end
```

on my run I got:

```
c =

    0.9773    1.0608    0.3673
    0.6670    0.1597    0.7296
    0.8372    1.1418    0.9828
```

and now mine:

```
squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, b, a), 2))
```

I get

```
ans =

    0.9773    1.0608    0.3673
    0.6670    0.1597    0.7296
    0.8372    1.1418    0.9828
```

so I am assuming mine is correct.

Explanation:

`bsxfun(@times, b, a)` does broadcasting, it expands `b` along it's singleton dimension (in this case dim 3) to match the size of `a` and then applies the function (`@times` is just `.*`) element by element to the expanded `b` and `a`. This is identical (but better practice and faster) to going `repmat(b, [1 1 size(a,3)]).*a`.

Then we sum this 3D matrix column wize like you have, i.e. `sum(x, 2)` which returns a 1x3x3 result. But I want a 3x3 result so to get rid of the singelton dimension (i.e. dim 1 as it equals 1) I used `squeeze`

It should be trivial for you to now vectorize your second line in the same way.

***BUT***

```
tic; for k = 1:10000 c = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, b, a), 2)); end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.394828 seconds.

tic; c = zeros(3,3); for k = 1:10000 for i=1:size(a,3)
c(:,i) = sum(b.*a(:,:,i),2);
end; end; toc
Elapsed time is 0.113199 seconds.
```

**THE NON-VECTORIZED CODE IS FASTER IN MATLASB 2012b!!!!!!!**

Comment: @camdroid Explanation added. But be warned, it is slower than a loop in newer matlabs (assuming you preallocate!)

Comment: @camdroid oh also I fixed an error, I had the `,2` as an argument to `squeeze` instead of to `sum` before, so just watch out for that

Comment: @camdroid Actually the speed test could be skewed because I used such small test matrices, perhaps you can test it on your actual data and let us know how the methods perform against each other?

Comment: You need to be a lot more careful with your timing tests.  Your should test what the OP actually does, not a simplified version of it.  You should try putting both versions of the code into m-files to see if that affects things (it did in older versions, but may not now).  You should also vary the size of your test sets, and use a bettering timing function than the `tic`/`toc` pair.  The [`timeit`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798) function was designed to avoid many timing mistakes.